# Each function applies to the first item

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<textarea id="bbcode_enabled"></textarea>
<textarea id="bbcode_enabled"></textarea>
<textarea id="bbcode_enabled"></textarea>

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#bbcode_enabled").each(function () { 
        $(this).bbcode({
            tag_bold:true,
            tag_italic:true,
            tag_underline:true,
            tag_link:true,
            tag_item:true,
            tag_skill:true,
            tag_own3d:true,
            tag_youtube:true,
            tag_twitch:true,
            tag_color:false,
            tag_image:true,
            button_image:true
        });
    });
});
```

It only applies the BBCode class to the first textarea, ignoring others.
What's wrong?

Ps. This is the BBCode class I'm using.
http://pastebin.com/FqXasEmD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `id`'s must be uniqiue, chage it to `class`:

```
<textarea class="bbcode_enabled"></textarea>
<textarea class="bbcode_enabled"></textarea>
<textarea class="bbcode_enabled"></textarea>

$(".bbcode_enabled").each(function () { 
    ...
});
```

Comment: It solved the issue, however all the BBCode images only applies to the top textarea now. Would u be able to look at it too or should I select this as the answer?

Comment: @LyverKinkki You may want to either update your question with more detail or start a new one if it is unrelated to the `.each()` only getting called once.